# Python web scraping Robinhood is inaccurate

Tags: python

I'm trying to scrape the stock price change (%) off of Robinhood but it keeps giving me an incorrect value. I'm not sure why this is happening, everything seems like it should work. Here's the python code:

```
def webScrape():
   my_url = 'https://robinhood.com/crypto/ETH'

   #opening up connection and grab page
   uClient = uReq(my_url)
   page_html = uClient.read()
   uClient.close()

   #html parsing
   page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

   #grab price diff %
   data = str(page_soup.findAll("span", {"class":"css-dq91k1"})[6].text)
   data = data[:-2]
   newData = ""
   for element in reversed(data):
      if element == '(':
         break
      else:
         newData += element
   newData = newData[::-1]
   return float(newData)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   print(webScrape())
```

The code is getting me a percentage, but it's the wrong one. I'm not sure why because here's the robin hood html from google chrome
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jhfY.png)

Here's an image of printing out more than just the text I was aiming at. The % daily change for ETH is at like -5% as you can see. I can't figure out what I'm grabbing and how what I'm grapping is wrong?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUqT5.png)

Comment: I think your code is okay. The value simply changes continuously.

Comment: No, it's definitely inaccurate. I can compare what I'm getting back to the hourly stock chart and it doesn't reach that percentage